# how to POST UIPickerview Value to JSON url

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, post, uipickerview

I have two `UITextFields`(cityNames,collageNames).I get data for JSON url.I get and Placed  data to `UIPickerview` based on `UITextFields`. when select `cityName` that city name placed into `UITextFields` but now I need that particular index value post to JSON URL and same as collage name 
. I know about String value Post to JSON url. But I don't know about How to post `UIPickerview` Index Value to JSON url.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
      NSLog(@"select row is %d",row);
    if(pickerView.tag==1){
     CityName.text = [secondArray objectAtIndex:row];

        string1=
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[yourpicker selectedRowInComponent:0]];
        NSLog(@"string ring %@",string1);

           }
    else if(pickerView.tag==2){
     CollageName.text = [firstArray objectAtIndex:row];

        string2=
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[yourpicker selectedRowInComponent:0]];

    }
}
```

String1 and String2 is get IndexValue .But i don't how to pass that particular Stringvalue to JSON.I tired but When i Print String 1 and 2 using NSLog outSide of Did-select Method it's showing null Values.When i Print String values in Didselect method it's showing select  Index value

```
 NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?&citynames=%@&collageNames=%@",cityname.text,collagename.text];
```

or

```
 NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?&citynames=%@&collageNames=%@",string1,string2];


    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.3.35:8090/SaveDollar/rest/users/add"]]];


    NSLog(@"getData%@",request);

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];

    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSLog(@"getData%@",request);


    con3 = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(con3)
    {      webData3=[NSMutableData data];
        NSLog(@"Connection successfull");
        NSLog(@"GOOD Day My data %@",webData3);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"connection could not be made");
    }
```

I tired like this (above code).i not getting.So Please give me any idea about How to post `UIPickerView` indexValue to JSON Url.

Thanks in Advanced .

Comment: do you want to post the index (e.g. "3") or the actual value (e.g. "Chandigarh University")?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann YES

Comment: @MichaelDautermann in textFiled showing "Chandigarh University" but Posting that number Please give me any idea

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Please give me any idea .i need showing in TextFeilds  (e.g. "Chandigarh University") but Post that index  (e.g. "3") like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different `pickerViews` so no issue.

Get the actual values from two different arrays as:

```
    NSString *collegeName=[collegeArray objectAtIndex:[self.dataPicker1 selectedRowInComponent:0]];
```

OR:

If you are able to see textField values, you can use them also as:

```
NSString *collegeName=collegeTextField.text;
```

One more way to get index i.e. from textField:

```
int index=[collegeNameArray indexOfObject:collegeName];
```

then you can pass `index` to your urlString.

To get the pickerView selected index use:

```
[self.dataPicker1 selectedRowInComponent:0]
```

You can build a urlString as:

```
urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?&citynames=%@&collageNames=%@",[self.dataPicker1 selectedRowInComponent:0],[self.dataPicker2 selectedRowInComponent:0]];
```

Comment: thanks for reply i need .i need showing in TextFeilds (e.g. "Chandigarh University") but Post that index (e.g. "3") like this So Please give me any idea

Comment: last line of answer gives you index

Comment: i know but please preetam i am new to this Please explain how to pass that index value to URL

Comment: i tried like this string1=
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[yourpicker selectedRowInComponent:0]];
        NSLog(@"string ring %@",string1); but when i print String 1 outside of Didselect method it's showing null value

Comment: thanks for reply But i used only one UIPickerview how can i do this

Comment: your answer fine when i using two Pickerviews But i used only one Pickerview So please give me any idea

Comment: i have two url so get data form two arrays.Two arrays data pass  to UIPickerview based on textField .